# Sending Thousands of Email per day without being spam

Tags: asp.net, email, spam-prevention, bulk-email

I'm having a website developed with ASP.NET  which is a online art competition that people can register and enroll with competition.

In my system there are lot of emails that sends on various stages of the process for a user.

As an example, one user gets:

1. Account confirmation email
2. Welcome email
3. Competition Instruction email
4. Password reset email
5. Payment confirmation email
6. Thank you email for completing the enrollment process.

Likewise I need to send various emails, so now the number of users registering per day is getting higher and higher.

So lets say there are more than 2000 - 5000. So there will be more than 10000 email sending from my noreply@mydomain.com email im using to send emails.

Anyway one email message only send for a one user. Meaning there is only one user email address in 'To:' field and no 'CC:','Bcc:' fields.

My question is is this considered as spamming ? I have a doubt that my email can be marked as spam. How i can avoid this? Is there any way to do it properly?

Comment: Most mail servers enforce a limit on number of emails per unit of time (usually per hour) in order to control server load.  You may need to pool your emails into batches in the same way that mailing lists do.  If you're not running your own server, maybe talk to your service provider about what restrictions are in place, and get them extended if you start running into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Managing your own mail server can be a pain. There's a lot to doing it right, and getting it wrong can mean landing on a blacklist. I recommend going with a service who has put in the time to ensure their e-mails get through.

You can find a rather exhaustive list of them here: [Sendgrid vs Postmark vs Amazon SES and other email/SMTP API providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798141/sendgrid-vs-postmark-vs-amazon-ses-and-other-email-smtp-api-providers)

Also, if you're sending e-mails in the US, be sure to follow the guidelines of the [CAN-SPAM Act](http://www.business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business).

Answer (score 0):

At least separate emails to **registered** users from registration/verification emails. Send them from different IP addresses.

Make sure that recipients want to receive you emails and they can **easily** opt-out at any moment (after initial opt-in) also **WITHOUT** log in to your service.